# Angular loop over Firestore data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Angular app using Firebase for hosting and Firestore for storing my data. I would like to create a function which reads all the data for a specific collection and loop over the documents to perform a certain action (upload to Google Drive, which has already been coded).

However, I am struggling to loop over the documents in my Firestore collection. This is my code to read the data from my "test" collection in Firestore:

```
read() {
    let result = [];

    this.firestore
      .collection("test")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(item => {
        item.map(row => {
          result.push(row.payload.doc.data());
        })
      })

    return result;
  }
```

In another component when I call this read() function and console.log it, I can see all data in the collection. However, when I try to loop over the documents and console.log them individually, it doesn't output anything.

```
async doSomething() {
    let allRows = await this.firebase.read();  // the function shown above
    console.log(allRows);  // I can see all the "rows"/documents in the collection

    allRows.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // but if I do this, it doesn't output anything
    console.log(allRows.length);  // even this outputs 0
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found the issue with my code. The issue is with assigning the result of the read operation to the variable `allRows`.

Instead of this:

`let allRows = await this.firebase.read();`

This worked for me:

```
let allRows: any;
await this.firebase.read().then(result => allRows = result);
```

Comment: if you are using await then no need to use then

Answer (score 0):

Your read method will not wait for the data from firestore since it is an asynchronous action and return blank array. You should change the read method like this

```
read() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let result = [];
      this.firestore
        .collection("test")
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(item => {
          Array.from(item).forEach(row => {
            result.push(row.payload.doc.data());
          });
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I have actually tried this before but then there is an error when I try to do forEach on the resulting array: `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: you can use map then.

Comment: I tried this as well, but same error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: updated my answer . please try and let me know if it  works?

Comment: Ok making progress, now I can see the expected result in the console but for some reason it's still throwing that error at the same time as well.

Comment: what is the error . from which method you are getting the error?

Comment: For example the `console.log(allRows.length)` still shows an error `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'unknown'.` but in the console it successfully outputted the correct number of documents in my collection.

Comment: first assign your allRows = Array.from(allRows). then use it

Comment: The same error still shows for `forEach` and `map` by the way.

Comment: Ok I tried your suggestion but now I get this error: `error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable<unknown> | ArrayLike<unknown>): unknown[]', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<unknown> | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
          Property 'length' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Overload 2 of 4, '(arrayLike: ArrayLike<unknown>): unknown[]', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of ....`

Comment: Ok I found the issue, I will post it below